# How to process elements of a list in python using multi threading without thread overlapping for each element?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a list of strings `l = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']`

I have a function to convert string to integer and return the number.

```
def to_int(s: str):
    print(int(s))
    return int(s)
```

I am beginner in multi threading with very minimal knowledge and to create a new thread in Python, I usually do this:

```
import time
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

def to_int(s: str):
    print(int(s))
    return int(s)

# create a new thread
t1 = Thread(target=to_int, args=(l[0],))

# start the thread
t1.start()

# wait for the thread to complete
t1.join()
```

[image]

I can see the output of the function when the new thread starts. Now I have a huge list of size 50,000 elements and I'd like to process the entire list in smaller batches and I prepared batching as below:

```
batch_size = 2
for i in range(0, len(l), batch_size):
    sub_list = l[i:i+batch_size]
```

Is there anyway I can process each element of the sublist parallelly by calling the method `to_int` in parallell threads?
For ex: In the first iteration, I have the sublist with elements: `['1', '2', '3']` and I want to process all three elements parallelly and only run the next batch once current batch is completed.
Could anyone let me know is there a way I can achieve this functionality? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: As I assume you don't want to start 50,000 threads. I recommend to change the `to_int()` function in such a way that it performs the conversion on a array slice. Then you create a thread for each array slice and merge the results.

Comment: In this case I would suggest multiprocessing instead of multithreading du the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). In that case, why not simply define the amount of processes you want to start in instead of batches slice your list into the set amount of process. In any case for converting a list of 50000 numbers into strings or vice versa doesn't take long (the printing in your function takes most of the time), so I'm not sure it is worth the hassle anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to work with `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` class like this:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

# your task
def to_int(s: str): 
    return int(s)

# test data
l = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

# create thread pool with 10 threads
pool = ThreadPool(processes=10)

# for each batch
batch_size = 2
for i in range(0, len(l), batch_size):
    sub_list = l[i:i+batch_size]
    # do the work
    print("batch", int(i/batch_size))
    for result in pool.map(to_int, sub_list):
        print(result)
```

Result:

```
batch 0
1
2
batch 1
3
4
batch 2
5
6
batch 3
7
8
batch 4
9
10
```

As already suggested I would not recommend to process every single element in a separate thread. It would be better if one thread processes an entire batch. But in the end it depends on your real task.

Comment: @Macro Is there any disadvantag if I run one element in one thread? Because I am already limiting the batch size to 2/3 and certainly not going to process 50K at a time, is there any overhead in this case?

Comment: @Torque It just depends on the actual task. For the example from your question it makes no sense to process each element separately. But if your task is more complex and needs more runtime per element it makes sense.

Comment: there is an API call in my task. There is lot of computation that goes before API call which is at the end of the script.

Comment: @Torque Then just try it that way. Don't overthink it, just try it out. If it makes problems you can also still optimize it

Comment: ok, one last question, is it processing 2 elements in that list parallelly?

Comment: @Torque yes sure. each element is processed on a thread. Add `time.sleep(5)`  to your `to_int()` function and you will see that both elements are processed after 5s, not 10s.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way for the manual method. The method that Marco provided is the ThreadPoolExecutor method. I tried to stick for the solution to be as similar to your question as possible.

```
import threading,time

# To create a list of string based integers to simulate the question.
lst = list(range(1,201))
lst1 = list(map(lambda x: str(x),lst))

# Function provided by the question
def to_int(s: str):
    print(int(s))
    return int(s)

batch_size = 4
# To see the sub-list groups
for i in range (0, len(lst1),batch_size):
    sub_list = lst1[i:i+batch_size]
    print(f"sub_list{i}:",end="")
    print(sub_list)
    

# Provided prints to easily visualize how the threads are processed.    
for i in range (0, len(lst1),batch_size):
    sub_list = lst1[i:i+batch_size]
    threads=[]
    for index in range(batch_size):
        print(f"Main : create and start thread {index}.")
        t = threading.Thread(target=to_int,name=str(index), args=(sub_list[index],))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for index, thread in enumerate(threads):
        print(f"Main : before thread {index}.")
        thread.join()
        print(f"Main : thread {index} done")
    print(f"All Threads completed for this sub_list{i}")
```

A part of the output will look as such:

```
All Threads completed for this sub_list188
Main : create and start thread 0.
Main : create and start thread 1.
Main : create and start thread 2.
Main : create and start thread 3.
Main : before thread 0.
Main : thread 0 done
Main : before thread 1.
Main : thread 1 done
Main : before thread 2.
Main : thread 2 done
Main : before thread 3.
Main : thread 3 done
All Threads completed for this sub_list192
Main : create and start thread 0.
Main : create and start thread 1.
Main : create and start thread 2.
Main : create and start thread 3.
Main : before thread 0.
Main : thread 0 done
Main : before thread 1.
Main : thread 1 done
Main : before thread 2.
Main : thread 2 done
Main : before thread 3.
Main : thread 3 done
All Threads completed for this sub_list196
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to do this in batches. Using map_async and a carefully calculated chunk size, you will get optimum performance.

Consider this:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from math import ceil
from time import perf_counter
from os import cpu_count

def to_int(v: str) -> int:
    try:
        return int(v)
    except ValueError:
        ...
    return -1

N = 50_000

# use half of available CPUs (minimum of 2)
if (NCPUS := cpu_count()):
    NCPUS = max(NCPUS//2, 2)
else:
    NCPUS = 2

# create N string representations of integer
my_list = [str(n) for n in range(N)]

with ThreadPool(NCPUS) as pool:
    chunksize = ceil(len(my_list) / NCPUS)
    start = perf_counter()
    results = list(pool.map_async(to_int, my_list, chunksize=chunksize).get())
    end = perf_counter()
    assert len(results) == N
    print(results[-20:])
    print(f'Duration={end-start:.4f}s')
```

**Output:**

```
[49980, 49981, 49982, 49983, 49984, 49985, 49986, 49987, 49988, 49989, 49990, 49991, 49992, 49993, 49994, 49995, 49996, 49997, 49998, 49999]
Duration=0.0094s
```

Comment: ok, what I don't understand from your snippet is how many parallell threads is it launching? Because the chunk size is coming out as 16667. I want to launch not more than 3to5 parallel threads. Is there anyway I can control the spawns in your code?

Comment: @DarkKinght Your implementation is intriguing, it would really help a ton if you can explain the thread configuration in your code i.e., where are you setting thread pool size and which parameters are those, the variables to control number of parallell threads, etc. Multi Threading Beginner problems.

Comment: @Torque Python's documentation on multiprocessing/multithreading is rather terse but the information is there if you care to look for it. You might also be inclined to take a look at https://superfastpython.com as an excellent resource

Answer (score 0):

Create a global mutable object, in this case list `result = list()`. Then modify the `to_int()` function to work on array slices.

```
def to_int(arr_slice):
    for i in arr_slice:
        result.append(int(i))
```

Now you can start a thread for each slice. You can choose the size of the array slice in such a way that it optimizes your thread use.

Result should now contain all of the integers from your original list converted to `int`.

Applied to your example with 3 threads:

```
l = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
r = list()

t1 = Thread(target=to_int, args=(l[:3],))
t2 = Thread(target=to_int, args=(l[3:6],))
t3 = Thread(target=to_int, args=(l[6:],))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to start & join these threads in a loop where I have the sublist?

Comment: I would consider the array slices as your batches, you can start the threads in a loop, but you have to keep track of the Thread objects in order to later  `join`. This can be done in a loop as well.

Comment: However personally I would just use a loop to process your list. 50,000 can be done very quickly and avoids all the additional work and potential issues you might walk into.